# To slecct the node in the TreeView ，but the node,s children automatically be selected ~

Tags: jquery

I only click the item "Tea" in the TreeView and change it,s background color，but it,s both childred item 'Black tea'、'Green tea' also automatically change them background color。

I don,t want to it,s both childred to change background color。  How can I do?

```
HTML=>

<ul  id="MenuTree"  class="demo1" >
    <li id ="A_Top" data-group="All" >All
          <ul>   
              <li id ="A_01" data-group="Coffee">Coffee</li>
              <li id ="A_02" data-group="Tea">Tea
                  <ul>
                      <li id ="A_04" data-group="Black tea">Black tea</li>
                      <li id ="A_05" data-group="Green tea">Green tea</li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li id ="A_03" data-group="Milk">Milk</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>



JavaScript=>


 $(document).on('click', '#MenuTree > li > ul  > li ', function (event) {


        if ($(event.target).closest('li').is(this)) {

            $(this).addClass('bg-info').siblings().removeClass('bg-info');
            //The code is invalid 
            $(this).children().children().removeClass('bg-info');


});
```

Comment: You should wrap label in element like span and then set background to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using CSS like,

```
.active{background:green} // let the active li bg would green.
.active ul, .active ul li {background:#FFF} // let the default color is white
```

Now what you have to do is that adding the `active` class to the parent li element.
For simplicity you can use `span` to wrap the li text like,

```
<ul  id="MenuTree"  class="demo1" >
    <li id ="A_Top" data-group="All" >All
          <ul>   
              <li id ="A_01" data-group="Coffee"><span>Coffee</span></li>
              <li id ="A_02" data-group="Tea"><span>Tea</span>
                  <ul>
                      <li id ="A_04" data-group="Black tea">Black tea</li>
                      <li id ="A_05" data-group="Green tea">Green tea</li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li id ="A_03" data-group="Milk">Milk</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

in jQuery add active class on clicking to span element like,

```
$('#MenuTree').on('click', 'li > span',function(){
    $('#MenuTree > li').removeClass('active'); // not required active for others
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: To wrap span is the very smart way , problem has been solved  , appreciate your help to provide , thank you very much~

Comment: Accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.